# A story about the Land of Id. The Land of Id was full of hate and crime. Perhaps a fable or a legend?

Tags: story-identification

They were so impoverished that when the children were too old for their mother's breast, they would be kicked out of the house. If they were good and didn't whine, they might be allowed to sleep in the parents' doorway at night.

I believe I heard it in grade school (in the 1980s in the Midwest). I do not know if I heard the whole story; I think the teacher just told us the gist of it in passing.

Comment: Was there a wizard who chanted "Frammin in the jim jam, frippin at the krotz!" ?

Comment: I dont think so. It would not have been a wizard type of story.